How to persist RateLimiter tokens?
I am using .Net RateLimiting and specifically the TokenBucketRateLimiter. Example:
services.AddRateLimiter(limiterOptions =>
{
    limiterOptions.AddPolicy(userPolicyName, context =>
    {
       string username = Utils.getUsername(context);
           return RateLimitPartition.GetTokenBucketLimiter
           (username , _ =>
               new TokenBucketRateLimiterOptions
               {
                   TokenLimit = myOptions.TokenLimit,
                   QueueProcessingOrder = QueueProcessingOrder.OldestFirst,
                   QueueLimit = 0,
                   ReplenishmentPeriod = TimeSpan.FromDays(myOptions.ReplenishmentPeriod),
                   TokensPerPeriod = myOptions.ReplenishmentPeriod,
                   AutoReplenishment = myOptions.AutoReplenishment
               });  
    });
});

This works, but doesn't survive service restarts (tokens get resetted every time the service restarts). From what I could find, it's using internally a memory store for tokens.
How can I change the store used for tokens? I'd prefer to use postgres for persistence if possible, but any kind of persistence will do.

You want to save on every request or on app shutdown?

It seems a little bit odd that you need this to survive a restart, does your app restart that often?

@Magnus I assume the safest option is to save on every request. The frequency of the app restart shouldn't matter, but yes, it will restart at least once daily, thus defeating my "replenish token every X days" strategy.

Refer to the asp.net core Radis Rate Limiting, you can try to access the dbContext in the custom rate limiting policies.
